# Horizontal oscillation motion by a spring when a resistive force is applied

Tags: spring, differential-equations, vibrations

I am curious to know how to solve the differential equation of horizontal oscillation motion by a spring when a resistive force is applied. Initial conditions, equation of motion and differential equations are shown in the picture.[image]

Comment: Welcome to SE. Please don't use screenshots and type the equations using the tools provided here.

Answer (score 0):

It's a very straightforward linear equation with constant coefficients. As a physicist I'd suggest knowing the solution by heart, but it's easy to find. I'll assume that $m$, $b$ and $k$ are real.

There's a polynom associated with this equation:

$$P(x)=mr^2+br+k$$

Let $r_1$ and $r_2$ be its roots. Depending on the discriminant $\Delta$'s sign, they can be real or complex. Assuming that $\Delta$ is non zero, the solutions are:

$$x(t)=Ae^{r_1t}+Be^{r_2t}$$

If $\Delta>0$, then you get (real) exponential solutions, so the system won't be able to oscillate due to strong friction.

If $\Delta<0$, then $r_1$ and $r_2$ are complexe conjugates, so you can rewrite $x(t)$ as a real oscillating function with exponentially decreasing amplitude.

After that, computing $A$ and $B$ from $x_0$ and $v_0$ is trivially easy.

Comment: Thank you very much!!